# Is it common that Big-O notation is rounded up to look better?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, file-recovery

Is it common that a higher value for Big-O notation is used for convenience or simpler looks?

For example: I'm looking at this algorithm "bifragment gap carving" shortly explained [here](http://digital-assembly.com/technology/research/pubs/ieee-spm-2009.pdf) (page 66). If I understand it correctly the algorithm would take for any gap size `n` a maximum of `sum from 1 to n` but in the same document it says:

> The technique does not scale for files fragmented with large gaps. If n is the number of clusters between bh and bz then in the worst case, n^2 object validations may be required
>   before a successful recovery.

So my question is: Do I understand the algorithm wrong or was the worst-case runtime rounded up to `n^2` to look nicer than a sum?

Comment: `O(n^2) = O(n*(n-1)/2)`

Comment: Rounding is relevant for exact values, you're dealing here with an asymptotic bound so the term doesn't apply.

Comment: Since the article doesn't mention big-O anywhere, I assume that `n^2` is the exact amount of object validations in the worst case.

Comment: Nico Schertler, you are right, sorry. But other articles I read for this algorithm actually used 'O(n^2)`. Thank you.

Comment: The question (and answers) are focusing on how `O(n^2+n)=O(n^2)`.  A more interesting question with the same title would be, for example, how common is `O(n^1.5 log n)` changed to `O(n^2)`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asymptotic analysis, not programming.

Comment: Big-O notation is rounded to the **dominant term**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the actual question: Yes, it's not just common but pretty much universal. O(N*N) means that the measure (usually runtime) goes up no faster than c * N *N for some unspecified c. Clearly N*N + N is smaller than 2 * N * N as N goes up, so O(N*N + N) is just O(N*N).

Answer (score 2):

'sum from 1 to n' indeed equals (n + 1) * n / 2, or (n^2 / 2 + n / 2)

So, the order of magnitude is `n^2` in this case. There is no simplification (you can obviously remove multiplicative constants like 1/2, and `n << n^2` when n is large.

Answer (score 1):

The function f given in O(f) is an upper bound for the complexity of an algorithm. It means that for all inputs of size n (bigger than a certain size n0), your algorithm does not use more time (or space) than const*f(n).

That menas that if your algorithm does sum(i, i=0...n)  steps ( which equals n*(n-1)/2 and is a quadratic function), const * n*n is a valid upper bound for all n>n0 --> and the complexity is O(n^2)

for another explanation look here:
[big o notation in plain english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o?rq=1)